# In a proof of the Riemann Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In a proof of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma in Hunter's Applies Analysis, he first proves the statement in the Schwartz space and then uses a density argument:
 [image]
[image]

Here are my **questions**:

- What goes wrong if one only assumes $\varphi\in L^1$ in the red box?
- In the very last line, why use $\liminf$ instead of $\lim$ directly?

Comment: Nothing goes wrong if you assume $\varphi\in L^1$ in the red box. As for the liminf, I'm not sure. I would not do that, personally. It is sufficient to just use the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument establishing the inequality for $\varphi\in\mathcal S$ would work just as well if it had been assumed only that $\varphi\in L^1$, but the author wanted to focus on $\mathcal S$ for a reason.  The space $\mathcal S$ is actually closed under the Fourier transform.  So $\widehat\varphi$, the Fourier transform of $\varphi\in\mathcal S$, is continuous. Later he shows a sequence of such Fourier transforms that are in $\mathcal S$ converges uniformly.  A sequence of continuous functions can converge in various senses to a discontinuous function, including pointwise convergence.  But if the convergence is uniform, then the limit is continuous.  And he shows that limit is the Fourier transform of the function in $L^1$ that he started with.  Thus he concludes that the Fourier transform of a function in $L^1$ is continuous.